# Неправильная сортировка uasort

Tags: php

Привет всем!
Есть такой код

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ( (int)$a < (int)$b ) return -1;
    if ( (int)$a = (int)$b ) return 0;
    if ( (int)$a > (int)$b ) return 1;
}
$s = array(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1);
uasort( $s, cmp );
```

Выдает "Array ( [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [4] => 0 [3] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [0] => 1 )"
Почему не происходит сортировки? В чем косяк?

PS До сих пор не ложился спать, так что голова тупит. Подозреваю, что ошибка какая-то очевидная, но уже не могу ее выловить, надеюсь на вашу внимательность =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//if ((int)$a = (int)$b)
if ((int)$a == (int)$b)
```

=)

Comment: Кстати, а чем плоха `function cmp($a, $b){return $a - $b;}` ?

Comment: Для  int - вроде как ничем, просто результат только знак проверяет, как я понимаю.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Хотя я тут нашел один момент: функция должна возвращать int, поэтому могут быть проблемы с float. Решается функцией gmp_sign.

Comment: Спасибо) Пример еще раз доказывает, что здоровый сон полезнее для проекта, чем пара лишних часов на отладку =)